# I can't install ati drivers ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati

I have a sony vaio laptop with a gpu ati mobility hd4650, and i want to install fglrx drivers but every time i try to do so i get an error.
The title of the error is: fglrx kernel failed to build.
The fglrx.0.crash is the following:

```
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
DKMS make.log for fglrx-8.960 for kernel 3.8.0-30-generic (i686)
Mon Sep 16 14:06:37 EEST 2013
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
kernel includes at /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build/include not found or incomplete
file: /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
DKMSKernelVersion: 3.8.0-30-generic
Date: Mon Sep 16 14:06:43 2013
DuplicateSignature:
 DKMS make.log for fglrx-8.960 for kernel 3.8.0-30-generic (i686)
 AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
 kernel includes at /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build/include not found or incomplete
 file: /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build/include/linux/version.h

FglrxBuildLog:
 AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
 .
 Active kernel:
 uname -a = Linux kormoranos-VGN-FW41M-H 3.8.0-30-generic #44~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 17:33:45 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
 uname -s = Linux
 uname -m = i686
 uname -r = 3.8.0-30-generic
 uname -v = #44~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 17:33:45 UTC 2013
 .
 Target kernel:
 uname -a = Linux kormoranos-VGN-FW41M-H 3.8.0-30-generic #44~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 17:33:45 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
 uname -s = Linux
 uname -m = i686
 uname -r = 3.8.0-30-generic
 uname -v = #44~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 17:33:45 UTC 2013
 .
 kernel includes at /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build/include not found or incomplete
 file: /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
Package: fglrx
PackageVersion: 2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1
SourcePackage: fglrx-installer
Title: fglrx 2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1: fglrx kernel module failed to build
ApportVersion: 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.4
Architecture: i386
Dependencies:
 adduser 3.113ubuntu2
 base-passwd 3.5.24
 binutils 2.22-6ubuntu1.1
 busybox-initramfs 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1
 coreutils 8.13-3ubuntu3.2
 cpio 2.11-7ubuntu3
 cpp 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 cpp-4.6 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 debconf 1.5.42ubuntu1
 debianutils 4.2.1ubuntu2
 dkms 2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.1
 dpkg 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1 [modified: sbin/start-stop-daemon]
 findutils 4.4.2-4ubuntu1
 fontconfig 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1
 fontconfig-config 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1
 gcc 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 gcc-4.6 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 gcc-4.6-base 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 ifupdown 0.7~beta2ubuntu8
 initramfs-tools 0.99ubuntu13.2
 initramfs-tools-bin 0.99ubuntu13.2
 initscripts 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1
 insserv 1.14.0-2.1ubuntu2
 iproute 20111117-1ubuntu2
 keyboard-configuration 1.70ubuntu5
 klibc-utils 1.5.25-1ubuntu2
 libacl1 2.2.51-5ubuntu1
 libattr1 1:2.4.46-5ubuntu1
 libaudio2 1.9.3-4
 libblkid1 2.20.1-1ubuntu3
 libbz2-1.0 1.0.6-1
 libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.4
 libc6 2.15-0ubuntu10.4
 libdb5.1 5.1.25-11build1
 libdbus-1-3 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4
 libdrm-intel1 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.2
 libdrm-nouveau1a 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.2
 libdrm-radeon1 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.2
 libdrm2 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.2
 libexpat1 2.0.1-7.2ubuntu1.1
 libffi6 3.0.11~rc1-5
 libfontconfig1 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1
 libfontenc1 1:1.1.0-1
 libfreetype6 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1
 libgcc1 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 libgcrypt11 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.2
 libglib2.0-0 2.32.3-0ubuntu1
 libgmp10 2:5.0.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1
 libgomp1 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 libgpg-error0 1.10-2ubuntu1
 libice6 2:1.0.7-2build1
 libjpeg-turbo8 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1
 libjpeg8 8c-2ubuntu7
 libklibc 1.5.25-1ubuntu2
 liblcms1 1.19.dfsg-1ubuntu3
 liblocale-gettext-perl 1.05-7build1
 liblzma5 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3
 libmng1 1.0.10-3
 libmount1 2.20.1-1ubuntu3
 libmpc2 0.9-4
 libmpfr4 3.1.0-3ubuntu2
 libncurses5 5.9-4
 libncursesw5 5.9-4
 libnih-dbus1 1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1
 libnih1 1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1
 libpam-modules 1.1.3-7ubuntu2
 libpam-modules-bin 1.1.3-7ubuntu2
 libpam0g 1.1.3-7ubuntu2
 libpciaccess0 0.12.902-1ubuntu0.2
 libpcre3 8.12-4
 libpixman-1-0 0.24.4-1
 libplymouth2 0.8.2-2ubuntu31.1
 libpng12-0 1.2.46-3ubuntu4
 libqt4-dbus 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libqt4-declarative 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libqt4-network 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libqt4-script 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libqt4-sql 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libqt4-xml 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libqt4-xmlpatterns 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libqtcore4 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libqtgui4 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4
 libquadmath0 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 libselinux1 2.1.0-4.1ubuntu1
 libslang2 2.2.4-3ubuntu1
 libsm6 2:1.2.0-2build1
 libstdc++6 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
 libtiff4 3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5
 libtinfo5 5.9-4
 libudev0 175-0ubuntu9.4
 libuuid1 2.20.1-1ubuntu3
 libx11-6 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2
 libx11-data 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2
 libxau6 1:1.0.6-4
 libxaw7 2:1.0.9-3ubuntu1
 libxcb1 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2
 libxcursor1 1:1.1.12-1ubuntu0.1
 libxdmcp6 1:1.1.0-4
 libxext6 2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.1
 libxfixes3 1:5.0-4ubuntu4.1
 libxfont1 1:1.4.4-1
 libxi6 2:1.6.0-0ubuntu2.1
 libxinerama1 2:1.1.1-3ubuntu0.1
 libxkbfile1 1:1.0.7-1ubuntu0.1
 libxmu6 2:1.1.0-3
 libxpm4 1:3.5.9-4
 libxrandr2 2:1.3.2-2ubuntu0.2
 libxrender1 1:0.9.6-2ubuntu0.1
 libxt6 1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
 libxxf86vm1 1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
 linux-headers-3.2.0-53 3.2.0-53.81
 linux-headers-3.2.0-53-generic 3.2.0-53.81
 linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.53.63
 linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-53.81
 lsb-base 4.0-0ubuntu20.3
 make 3.81-8.1ubuntu1.1
 makedev 2.3.1-89ubuntu2
 module-init-tools 3.16-1ubuntu2
 mount 2.20.1-1ubuntu3
 mountall 2.36.4
 multiarch-support 2.15-0ubuntu10.4
 ncurses-bin 5.9-4
 passwd 1:4.1.4.2+svn3283-3ubuntu5.1
 patch 2.6.1-3
 perl-base 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.3
 plymouth 0.8.2-2ubuntu31.1
 procps 1:3.2.8-11ubuntu6
 sed 4.2.1-9
 sensible-utils 0.0.6ubuntu2
 sysv-rc 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1
 sysvinit-utils 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1
 tar 1.26-4ubuntu1
 ttf-dejavu-core 2.33-2ubuntu1
 tzdata 2013d-0ubuntu0.12.04
 ucf 3.0025+nmu2ubuntu1
 udev 175-0ubuntu9.4
 upstart 1.5-0ubuntu7.2 [modified: sbin/initctl]
 util-linux 2.20.1-1ubuntu3
 x11-common 1:7.6+12ubuntu2
 x11-xkb-utils 7.6+4
 xkb-data 2.5-1ubuntu1.3
 xserver-common 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.13
 xserver-xorg-core 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.13
 xz-utils 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3
 zlib1g 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4
DistroCodename: precise
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 12.04
DistroVariant: ubuntu
InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS "Precise Pangolin" - Release i386 (20130820.1)
MarkForUpload: True
PackageArchitecture: i386
ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 3.8.0-30.44~precise1-generic 3.8.13.6
Tags:  precise ubuntu
Uname: Linux 3.8.0-30-generic i686
UnreportableReason: Please work this issue through technical support channels first.
UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
```

I also tried to install the drivers from amd website but again i get an error.
Is there anything i can do about it???